# How to format odd headers when adding to the TIdHTTP component via AddValue()

Tags: delphi, header, indy, idhttp

I am using

```
idhttp.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue(x,y);
```

This is working fine for me, but now I have come across a different header and am not sure how to add it or what value, string to use.

In the past, I have used

```
'SOAPACTION','http://url/action'
```

But what would I need to do for the `mustUnderstand` part, or in the `ReplyTo` and `Address` parts?

How would I `AddValue(x,y)` them?

I have tried

```
...AddValue('SOAPACTION','http://URL/Action');
...AddValue('mustUnderstand','1');
```

But I am getting errors, and the host IT says that my headers are not correct.

```
<s:Header>
<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://URL/Action</a:Action>
<a:MessageID>A Valid GUIID</a:MessageID>
<a:ReplyTo>
<a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
</a:ReplyTo>
<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">URL STRING</a:To>
</s:Header>
```

Previous simple headers have worked, but I am not sure how to add these headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SOAPAction` is a valid HTTP header for SOAP messaging, but `mustUnderstand` and `ReplyTo` **are not HTTP headers**, so DO NOT add them with `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue()` at all. They are components of the `<Header>` element inside of a SOAP `<Envelope>` message, so they belong inside the XML data that you post to the server via `TIdHTTP` (as per the example XML that you showed). You are confusing HTTP headers and SOAP headers. They are two different things.

If the webserver IT is telling you that your HTTP or SOAP headers are wrong, it should also be telling you what exactly is wrong with them so you can fix it.

This is not an Indy issue.  You are simply not preparing your SOAP message the way the webserver is expecting.  But we don't have those details to advise you with.  The webserver IT does.

Comment: sorry but just one more question is the s:action even a soap header or just the part of the xml that i need to send. The IT is a state agency and info from them is piped thru the client and then back to me. the format came thru them to me so i was just assuming it was a soapheader and not just part of the xmlrequest.

Comment: @RDT I suggest you read the relevant SOAP specs, and ask the client for clarification on requirements.